# Catch `Get-ChildItem` errors on a file-by-file basis

Tags: powershell

I'm using `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` to search a directory. I can't guarantee that everything `Get-ChildItem` will hit will be accessible. I want to log these failures, but not fail the entire `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` command. Right now I have

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $targetdir -ErrorAction Inquire `
        | where { $_.Name -eq $name } `
        | foreach {
            echo-indented "Found $(hash $_) at $($_.FullName)"
            $_
        }
```

The code in question is the `-ErrorAction Inquire`. If I did `-ErrorAction Stop`, I would have to put a try-catch somewhere. It would have to be around the entire pipeline, right? In that case, childitems that would have been found after the inaccessible one will not be found and written out. So what else can I do?

Comment: Did you try `WhatIf` ? That asks you if you want to continue with the command (If I understand your question correctly that you want to set it on a file-by-file basis.

Comment: I don't even want it to ask, or I would just keep Inquire. I want it to continue, logging the error in a particular way.

Comment: What error do you expect to get? As far as I see you are only looking for files which have a certain name, or am I missing something?

Comment: I am wondering if this is really an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Note that you can analyze the `$Error` collection afterwards… Example: `$error.Clear(); ls -Recurse $targetdir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Filter "$name"; $Error.Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

For `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`, specifying the `-ErrorAction` won't really help you here. It will only cause access deny errors to either be:

- Terminating (`-ErrorAction Stop`) where everything just stops. (not what you want)
- Non-terminating (the default `-ErrorAction Continue`) which is what you want, as it will continue.

As for logs, with the default `-ErrorAction Continue`, all access denies are logged to the `$Error` variable. We can then parse through the exception records to get the information that we need:

```
#Start by clearing the error variable 
$Error.Clear()

#Execute Get-ChildItem with -ErrorAction Continue

ls -Recurse $targetdir -ErrorAction Continue `
    | where { $_.Name -EQ $name } `
    | foreach {
        echo-indented "Found $(hash $_) at $($_.FullName)"
        $_
    }

#Display objects we got Access Denies on:
$Error | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.TargetObject
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-ErrorVariable` common parameter to save the errors to a variable.

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse foo -ErrorVariable err
$err
```